# How would you fill out the blanks in this document? "Done at ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I am applying for a scholarship and I must fill out this page. I've never seen "Done at" phrase before. And, also at the beginning, there is `I......... country........................date of birth`.

So, how would this `John Smith` fill out this document?

`First name:` John

`Last name:` Smith

`Date of birth:` 1/1/2000

`Country:` Paris, France

I am more concerned about filling it out in a way that creates a reasonable sentence with what comes after these blanks.

[image]

Comment: It is strangely worded, presumably because it was not drawn up by native speakers of English. Presumably 'done at' asks for the place where the document was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are an Italian currently in Rome

At the beginning you fill out

> I Giorgio Aptsiauri, country Italy, date of birth 1 Jan 1990

At the end

> Done at Rome on October 26 2020

As @KateBunting suggested in a comment forms in the UK do not usually ask you to say where you filled it out but in some countries this is more common.

Comment: *"in some countries this is more common"* Do you know this to be true, or are you just guessing? What evidence do you have that this is true?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I have had to fill out forms originating in Belgium and also forms originating in Spain which used the formulation which the OP quotes. It may be used elsewhere, I have no further evidence.

Comment: - Okay, that's good enough evidence for me that other places do it.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I have done an image search for Spanish documents and they do have place and date although I agree with you that theoretically it could be the time.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "Done at" is completely unfamiliar in English. This is an imperfect translation. I think it means "My declaration is made at ..."

Even then there is a problem. "at" could refer to a time or to a place.

So the answer could be

*Done at 10.15 am on 26 October 2020*

or it could be

*Done at 25 La Rue Marie-Stuart, Paris on 26 October 2020*

I believe that the most likely is that they require the time, although I can't be certain.

---

You could put both of those things but my advice is to call the office of the department and simply ask whether they require a time or a place in that slot.